# Converting a physical book into ebook for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I intend to convert a physical book into a ebook for iPhone. I am interested in finding out what are the steps that I need to do in order to do this. Need some guidance as well as suggestions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.  And why the hell isn't this an official close reason I can't figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) If you are intending on distributing this book in any way (using for anything besides your own personal use), you will need to obtain copyrights to the material (unless you wrote it).

2) Get images of all the pages onto a computer by scanning it or using a digital camera.

3) Use an [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) program to generate text. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_character_recognition_software) is a list.

4) Use a page layout, word processing, or book writing program to compile the text into a document. These include Pages from iWork (word processing and page layout), iBook Author, Word from Microsoft Office (word processing), Adobe Illustrator (page layout, comes with Adobe Creative Suite), and numerous others. Open Office might be good enough.

5) Export the document as a PDF or ePub. iPhones and iPads also recognize Kindle and B&N eBook formats.

Comment: This is a fast answer. If the person is asking, there's a chance they wouldn't know what this stuff means and are looking for steps.

Comment: @EliGregory Does that look better?

Comment: @lakesh No problem. I have some experience with this, and it is a pretty tedious process. You could try using a command-line OCR program and a web-cam. Build a shell script to snap an image and run it through OCR every second or so. Then all you have to do is flip the page every second.